# Android MapView in ListView Header is not calling onTouchEvent

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, android-mapview, android-touch-event

I have a ListView where I add a Google Map **MapView** into the header view, below is the code on how I do that:

```
vListViewTrips.addHeaderView(vMapHeaderView, null, false);
```

The map is shown and works but the map does not handle any gestures when its being touched even though all gestures are anebled by: `googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);`

Based on some searches that I did I tried to `extend MapView` and override the `public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent motionEvent)` but still the `onTouchEvent` of the **MapView** is never called.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent motionEvent) {


    ViewParent viewparent = getParent();
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        // Pressed on map: stop listview from scrolling
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            viewparent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            viewparent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        // Released on map or cancelled: listview can be normal again
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            viewparent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}
```

Note im using `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the `ListView` touch methods in order to return `false`, so that events continue propagating to view's children ?

I mean create a custom view, extending the `ListView`, and using it instead.

Comment: I'll try it out now